# Circuit board inside a charging cable

Tags: security, smartphones

[image][image]I am looking for help identifying a circuit board found inside one of the ends of a charging cable that mysteriously showed up on the desk in my home office. The board has the following stamped on it:

TX-J2ON
V 1.1 20200622

The charging cable is comprised of a male USB connection on one end and a male micro USB on the other. This end also has an adapter to a male lightning connector. Inside this adapter is where the circuit was found.

I would like to know if this is something potentially used for malicious purposes.

Thanks

Comment: ? https://www.amazon.ca/Belkin-Micro-USB-Lightning-Connector-Adapter/dp/B00IDI70SQ

Comment: The question can be interpreted not just broad, but with more than one meaning; we all could benefit of a more specific information. For instance: all Lightning cables need to have an internal circuit to convert USB to lightning and vice-versa. This is usually molded in plastic, close to the lightning side, and being difficult to disassemble. However, if it is another “circuit board”, a photo could help to clarify the matter. 
That number sequence seems to be date as YYYYMMDD and “googling” the remaining codification does not provide any useful reference.

Comment: Hello Tony - Thanks for your response. Do all of these types of cables have the type circuit board described, or a comparable one? I have been reading about the O.MG cable and the technology behind it.

Comment: USB-C cables also have ICs in the connector to negotiate maximum current and voltage(the cable can handle) with the power supply.

Answer (score 3):

The lightning connector has exposed contacts on the live side, unlike any other usb connector - usually leaving live contacts exposed is a bad design choice as they can short and destroy your device or cause fires. To compensate for this design choice active components are placed in the end to only switch power on when it senses that it’s plugged in to something. All the apple factory spec cables are like this and any good third party cable must implement a system of this nature

That being said Any chip labeled “007” is probably a spy (a joke!)